# Como evitar a propagação do método toggleClass no evento de click

Tags: jquery, html

No código abaixo eu tenho dois **toggleClass**(são no total 12) que estão funcionando corretamente, porem eu preciso que seja expandido **somente 1**, ou seja, se eu expandir o `primeiro` e depois o segundo, imediatamente o `primeiro` deve reprimir-se. No momento, não acontece isso. Execute o código abaixo e clique nos **"+"**:

```js
// when DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 mapItems = $("div.map").find("div img.mapItem");
 
 var tempItem;

 for(var i = 0; i < mapItems.length; i++){
  
  tempItem = mapItems[i];
  
  $(tempItem).click(function($e){

   //Evita o scroll mudar com o click
      $e.preventDefault();
   $e.stopPropagation();

      //Obtendo valor do data-desc
      var desc = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").attr("data-desc");
   var modals = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").attr("data-modals");
   titulodata = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").attr("data-titulocarrossel");
   desccarrossel = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").attr("data-desccarrossel");
      //Adcionando descrição
   $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").html('<p class="descs ' + modals + ' ">'+desc+'</p>'); 
  
      //Criando a função toggle para a utilização da class modal-celebration(balão)
      $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").toggleClass("modal-celebration " + modals); 

      //Obtendo o boolean
      var isVisible = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").is( ":visible" );
      var isHidden = $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").is( ":hidden" );   
      
   //Verificando estado    
   if (isVisible) {
    $(".borda").delay(700).fadeIn(500);
    $("#selectLocation").stop().fadeOut(500);
    $("#galleryContainer").stop().fadeOut(200, onHideGalleryComplete);

   }else{
    $(".borda").delay(700).fadeOut(500);
    $("#galleryContainer").stop().fadeOut(200);
    $("#selectLocation").stop().fadeIn(500);
   }

   //rotacionando
    $(this).toggleClass("down"); 
  
  });
 
  
  $(tempItem).click(function(){
  

   TituloEmprendimento = '<h3>' + titulodata +'</h3><p class="desc-carrossel">'+ desccarrossel +'</p>';  
  
   
  });
 };
 
})

function onHideGalleryComplete(){
 loadXMLEntries();
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:#fff;
 }

 /*** main layout ***/

 .main{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  
  width: 810px;
  height: 1160px;
  
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 .preloader{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  
  width: 810px;
  height: 1160px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color:#000;
 }
 .preloaderImg{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 44px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -55px;
 }


 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Century_Gothic';
     src: url('../font/Century_Gothic.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Century_Gothic_BOLD';
     src: url('../font/Century_Gothic_BOLD.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica';
   src: url('../font/Helvetica.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

 .lote p{
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial!important;
 }

 h3 {
     font-size: 24px;
     font-family: 'Century_Gothic', sans-serif!important;
     color: #fff!important;
 }


 .map{
  display:block;
  width: 810px;
  height: 760px;
  
  background-image:url(../img/map-bg2.jpg);
  
 }

 .logo{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 68px auto;
  
 }

 .logo h1{
     width: 730px;
     margin: -13px auto;
     font-size: 55px;
     font-weight: bold;
 }

 .tagline{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  
  width: 354px;
  height: 41px;
  margin-left: -183px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 130px;
 }

 .galleryBox{
  background: url(../img/bg-galeria.jpg);
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  left: 0%;
  top: 760px;
  
  width: 810px;
  height: 300px;
  
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 }

 .galleryName{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 689px;
  left: 37px;
  text-align: left;
  top: -3px;
 }


 .selectLocation{
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     left: 0%;
     top: 760px;
     width: 810px;
     height: 300px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }

 .footer{
  background-image:url(../img/footer-bg.png);
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width: 810px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 1060px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .celebration{
     position: absolute;
     width: 160px;
     height: 97px;
     left: 84%;
     top: -17px;
 }


 .instagramFollow{
     position: absolute;
     width: 162px;
     height: 95px;
     left: 36px;
     top: 14px;
 }

 /*** gallery stuff ***/

 #galleryContainer {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }

 #galleryTopContainer {
  width: 728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .galleryPictureList {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  width:0px;
 }

 .galleryPictureItem {
     display: inline-block;
     zoom: 1;
 }

 .galleryBoxPicture{
      margin-top: 102px;
      width: 240px;
      margin-left: 4px;
      height: 177px;

 }
 .galleryBoxDescription{
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  display:none;  
  width: 44px;
  height: 50px;  
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;   
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  
  color:#DDD;
  padding:5px;
 }

 .galleryArrowBtn {
  position:absolute;  
  width:66px;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }

 .galleryArrowBtn:hover {
  background-position:-66px 0px;
 }

 .galleryArrowLeft {  
  visibility:hidden;  
  left: 41px;
     top: 102px;
  background-image:url(../img/arrowLeft.png);
 }

 .galleryArrowRight {  
  visibility:hidden;
  left: 724px;
     top: 102px;
  background-image:url(../img/arrowRight.png);
 }

 /*** other ***/

 .mapItem{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
 }

 .mapLabel{ 
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
 }
 .mapDesc{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 256px;
     height: 106px;
 }

 

 
 /*** PORTICO ***/

 #z-in-portico-build{
     z-index: 1!important;
  position: relative;
  right: 433px;
        top: -99px;
  width: 1px;
 }


 #portico-build{
  z-index: 1!important;
  left: 495px;
  top: 180px;

 }

 #portico-build-desc{
  display:none;
  background-image:url(../img/descriptions/descri.png);
  left: 483px;
  top: 55px;
 }

 #portico-build-img{
  right: -447px;
  top: 181px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
 }



 /*** CASA ***/

 #z-in-casa-build{
        z-index: 0!important;
  position: relative;
  right: 98px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 1px;
 }


 #casa-build{
  z-index: 1!important;
  left: 547px;
     top: 31px;

 }

 #casa-build-desc{
  display:none;
  background-image:url(../img/descriptions/descri.png);
  left: 533px;
     top: -97px;
 }

 #casa-build-img{
  right: -496px;
     top: 32px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
 }
    

 
  /*** STREET ***/

 #z-in-street-park-build{
        z-index: 0!important;
  position: relative;
  right: 344px;
        top: -59px;
  width: 1px;
 }


 #street-park-build{
  z-index: 1!important;
     left: 557px;
     top: 142px;

 }

 #street-park-build-desc{
  display:none;
  background-image:url(../img/descriptions/descri.png);
  left: 533px;
     top: 8px;
 }

 #street-park-build-img{
    right: -509px;
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
 }




 /*** POR GERAL***/ 


 #z-in-portico-geral-build{
  z-index: 0!important;
  position: relative;
  right: 280px;
  top: 141px;
  width: 1px;
 }


 #portico-geral-build{
  z-index: 1!important;
  left: 547px;
     top: 31px;

 }

 #portico-geral-build-desc{
  display:none;
  background-image:url(../img/descriptions/descri.png);
  left: 533px;
     top: -97px;
 }

 #portico-geral-build-img{
  right: -496px;
     top: 32px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
 }



/* ----------------------------------------*/

 .redes{ 
  width: 387px;
     float: left;
     color: #fff;
 }

 .redes ul{ width: 200px; }

 .redes ul li{  
  width: 25px;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 16px;
     margin-top: 21px;
 }

 .lote{
  width: 645px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
 }
    

   p.p-top{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -43px;
    top: 192px;
    width: 280px;
    text-align: right;
   }

   p.p-bot{
 font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 238px;
    top: 209px;
    width: 280px;
    text-align: right;
   }

   p {     
     font-family: 'Century_Gothic', 
     sans-serif; color: #fff; 
    }

   .redes p {font-family: 'Century_Gothic_BOLD', sans-serif;   }


 .rotate{
     -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
     transition: all 0.5s linear;
 }


 .rotate.down{
     -moz-transform:rotate(225deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotate(225deg);
     transform:rotate(225deg);
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes overlayfx {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(.8); opacity: 0; }
    100%   { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); opacity: 1;  z-index: 1; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes  overlayfx {
    0% { -moz-transform: scale(.8); opacity: 0; }
    100%   { -moz-transform: scale(1.1); opacity: 1;  z-index: 1;  }
 }
 @keyframes overlayfx {
    0% { transform: scale(.8); opacity: 0; }
    100%   { transform: scale(1.1); opacity: 1;  z-index: 1;  }
 }


 .modal-celebration {
   display: block!important;
   width: 158px;
   height: 158px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
   -webkit-animation: overlayfx 0.3s linear 0.1s 1 forwards;  
   -moz-transform: scale(.8);
   -moz-animation: overlayfx 0.3s linear 0.1s 1 forwards;  
   transform: scale(.8);
   animation: overlayfx 0.3s linear 0.1s 1 forwards;

 }

p.descs.portico-build {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2B467D;
    position: relative;
    top: 72px;
    left: -49px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 156px;
    font-size: 15px;
}



p.descs.street-park-build {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2B467D;
    position: relative;
    top: 68px;
    left: -32px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 148px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div id="map" class="map">
  
        
        <!-- LOCAIS -->
        
         <div id="z-in-portico-build">
             <div class="mapDesc" data-titulocarrossel="LOCAL1" data-desccarrossel="LOCAL1" data-desc="LOCAL1" data-modals="portico-build" id="portico-build-desc" style="display: none;"></div>
            
            <a href="#"><img src="https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/tab-face/celebrationville/pin.png" class="mapItem itemDefault rotate" id="portico-build"/></a>
          
        </div>

       
        <div id="z-in-street-park-build">
        <div class="mapDesc" data-titulocarrossel="LOCAL2" data-desccarrossel="LOCAL2" data-desc="LOCAL2" data-modals="street-park-build" id="street-park-build-desc" style="display: none;"></div>
            
            <a href="#"><img src="https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/tab-face/celebrationville/pin.png" class="mapItem itemDefault rotate" id="street-park-build"/></a>
           
        </div>

       
</div>

   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Se é "um de cada vez" então está como esperado. Mas talvez o que você quer é que quando um estiver ativo/aberto o outro deve está desativado/fechado. Se é o caso você deveria esclarecer.

Comment: Isso! Sabe como resolver?

Comment: Puxa, tem tantas formas de resolver pois isso é tão trivial. O mais estranho é que se você fez isso tudo deveria ser fácil também pra resolver isso. O que eu faria era isolar isto em métodos/funções especializadas. Haveria uma função tal como *aplicarEventos(elmentos, callback)*. Então o 2º parâmetro seria um função como *exibir(elemento)* que ativa/mostra o elemento clicado e fecha todos os outros elementos abertos anteriormente. Isso não só funciona com 2 eleentos como também com inúmeros, exatamente como em um componente do tipo *accordion*.

Comment: Entende a ideia? Eu quase não posto mais aqui pois isso está uma bagunça, o pessoal sai negativando as respostas de uma forma estranha (há uns maria-vai-com-as-outras).

Comment: @felipsmartins, eu também estava percebendo isso, há algum tempo, mas depois aprendi que na verdade aqui é organizado a ponto de você precisar brilhar na resposta para poder ser positivado. Ajuda awe , mano!

Comment: Eu farei e postarei o link aqui nos comentários. Me dê um minutinho, por favor.

Comment: @felipsmartins, ta dando certo?

Comment: aqui está o link de exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/72jjj1ne/

Comment: Descobri por que é negativado, brother, você não desenvolve sua resposta a partir da pergunta, mas cria algo alternativo, as vezes complexo, que requer mais trabalho, pois há pouca explicação. MAS MUITO OBRIGADO! APRENDI MUITO. Você é um ótimo desenvolvedor javascript, pensa e faz. Parabéns.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução para fazer oque você pretende.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $descritions = $('div[id*="z-in-"] .mapDesc');
  var $buttons = $('div[id*="z-in-"] a');
  var $rotates = $('img.rotate');
  var toggleClasses = 'modal-celebration portico-build';

  $buttons.on('click', function($e) {

    //Evita o scroll mudar com o click
    $e.preventDefault();
    $e.stopPropagation();
    
    var $self = $(this);
    var $prev = $self.prev();
    var $current = $prev.is('.modal-celebration.portico-build');

    //Obtendo valor do data-desc
    var desc = $prev.data("desc");
    var modals = $prev.data("modals");
    var titulodata = $prev.data("titulocarrossel");
    var desccarrossel = $prev.data("desccarrossel");
      
    //Adcionando descrição
    $prev.html('<p class="descs ' + modals + ' ">' + desc + '</p>');
        
    //Criando a função toggle para a utilização da class modal-celebration(balão)
    $prev.toggleClass("modal-celebration " + modals);
    
    //Verificando estado
    if ($current) {
        $(".borda").delay(700).fadeIn(500);
        $("#selectLocation").stop().fadeOut(500);
        $("#galleryContainer").stop().fadeOut(200, onHideGalleryComplete);

      } else {
        $(".borda").delay(700).fadeOut(500);
        $("#galleryContainer").stop().fadeOut(200);
        $("#selectLocation").stop().fadeIn(500);
      }
        
    $descritions.removeClass(toggleClasses);
    $rotates.removeClass("down");
    
    if (!$current) {
      $index = $self.index($buttons);
      $descritions.eq($index).addClass(toggleClasses);
      $self.find('img.rotate').addClass('down');
    }
         
  });

})

function onHideGalleryComplete() {
  loadXMLEntries();
}
```

```css
.main,.preloader{width:810px;height:1160px}body{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#fff}.main{display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.preloader,.preloaderImg{position:absolute;display:block}.preloader{top:0;left:0;background-color:#000}.preloaderImg{width:100px;height:44px;top:40%;left:50%;margin-left:-50px;margin-top:-55px}@font-face{font-family:Century_Gothic;src:url(../font/Century_Gothic.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:Century_Gothic_BOLD;src:url(../font/Century_Gothic_BOLD.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:Helvetica;src:url(../font/Helvetica.ttf) format('truetype')}.lote p{font-family:Helvetica,Arial!important}h3{font-size:24px;font-family:Century_Gothic,sans-serif!important;color:#fff!important}.map{display:block;width:810px;height:760px;background-image:url(../img/map-bg2.jpg)}.galleryBox,.tagline{display:none;position:absolute}.logo{position:absolute;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:68px auto}.logo h1{width:730px;margin:-13px auto;font-size:55px;font-weight:700}.tagline{width:354px;height:41px;margin-left:-183px;left:50%;top:130px}.galleryBox,.selectLocation{height:300px;padding:0;margin:0}.galleryBox{background:url(../img/bg-galeria.jpg);left:0;top:760px;width:810px}.footer,.galleryArrowBtn{background-repeat:no-repeat}.galleryName{display:block;position:absolute;width:689px;left:37px;text-align:left;top:-3px}.footer,.selectLocation{display:none;width:810px;position:absolute}.selectLocation{left:0;top:760px}.footer{background-image:url(../img/footer-bg.png);height:100px;top:1060px}.celebration{position:absolute;width:160px;height:97px;left:84%;top:-17px}.instagramFollow{position:absolute;width:162px;height:95px;left:36px;top:14px}#galleryContainer{position:relative;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%}#galleryTopContainer{width:728px;margin:0 auto;height:300px;overflow:hidden}.galleryPictureList{position:relative;left:0;width:0}.galleryPictureItem{display:inline-block;zoom:1}.galleryBoxPicture{margin-top:102px;width:240px;margin-left:4px;height:177px}.galleryBoxDescription{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;position:absolute;bottom:0;display:none;width:44px;height:50px;margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);color:#DDD;padding:5px}.galleryArrowBtn{position:absolute;width:66px;height:100%}.galleryArrowBtn:hover{background-position:-66px 0}.mapDesc,.mapItem,.mapLabel{display:block;position:absolute;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 0}.galleryArrowLeft{visibility:hidden;left:41px;top:102px;background-image:url(../img/arrowLeft.png)}.galleryArrowRight{visibility:hidden;left:724px;top:102px;background-image:url(../img/arrowRight.png)}.mapItem{cursor:pointer;cursor:hand}.mapLabel{width:250px;height:100px}.mapDesc{width:256px;height:106px}#casa-build-desc,#portico-build-desc,#portico-geral-build-desc,#street-park-build-desc{display:none;background-image:url(../img/descriptions/descri.png)}#z-in-portico-build{z-index:1!important;position:relative;right:433px;top:-99px;width:1px}#portico-build{z-index:1!important;left:495px;top:180px}#portico-build-desc{left:483px;top:55px}#portico-build-img{right:-447px;top:181px;position:relative;z-index:-2}#z-in-casa-build{z-index:0!important;position:relative;right:98px;top:8px;width:1px}#casa-build,#portico-geral-build{z-index:1!important;left:547px;top:31px}#casa-build-desc,#portico-geral-build-desc{left:533px;top:-97px}#casa-build-img,#portico-geral-build-img{right:-496px;top:32px;position:relative;z-index:-2}#z-in-street-park-build{z-index:0!important;position:relative;right:344px;top:-59px;width:1px}#street-park-build{z-index:1!important;left:557px;top:142px}#street-park-build-desc{left:533px;top:8px}#street-park-build-img{right:-509px;top:150px;position:relative;z-index:-2}#z-in-portico-geral-build{z-index:0!important;position:relative;right:280px;top:141px;width:1px}.redes{width:387px;float:left;color:#fff}.redes ul{width:200px}.redes ul li{width:25px;float:left;margin-left:16px;margin-top:21px}.lote{width:645px;float:left;color:#fff;font-size:7px;text-align:left;position:relative;top:-8px}p.p-bot,p.p-top{font-size:15px;margin:0 0 10px;float:right;position:relative;width:280px;text-align:right;color:#fff}p.p-top{left:-43px;top:192px}p.p-bot{left:238px;top:209px}p{font-family:Century_Gothic,sans-serif;color:#fff}.redes p{font-family:Century_Gothic_BOLD,sans-serif}.rotate{-moz-transition:all 2s linear;-webkit-transition:all 2s linear;transition:all .5s linear}.rotate.down{-moz-transform:rotate(225deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(225deg);transform:rotate(225deg)}@-webkit-keyframes overlayfx{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(.8);opacity:0}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);opacity:1;z-index:1}}@-moz-keyframes overlayfx{0%{-moz-transform:scale(.8);opacity:0}100%{-moz-transform:scale(1.1);opacity:1;z-index:1}}@keyframes overlayfx{0%{transform:scale(.8);opacity:0}100%{transform:scale(1.1);opacity:1;z-index:1}}.modal-celebration{display:block!important;width:158px;height:158px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(.8);-webkit-animation:overlayfx .3s linear .1s 1 forwards;-moz-transform:scale(.8);-moz-animation:overlayfx .3s linear .1s 1 forwards;transform:scale(.8);animation:overlayfx .3s linear .1s 1 forwards}p.descs.portico-build,p.descs.street-park-build{font-weight:700;color:#2B467D;position:relative;text-align:center;font-size:15px}p.descs.portico-build{top:72px;left:-49px;width:156px}p.descs.street-park-build{top:68px;left:-32px;width:148px}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="map" class="map">
    <!-- LOCAIS -->
    <div id="z-in-portico-build">
      <div class="mapDesc" data-titulocarrossel="LOCAL1" data-desccarrossel="LOCAL1" data-desc="LOCAL1" data-modals="portico-build" id="portico-build-desc" style="display: none;"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/tab-face/celebrationville/pin.png" class="mapItem itemDefault rotate" id="portico-build" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="z-in-street-park-build">
      <div class="mapDesc" data-titulocarrossel="LOCAL2" data-desccarrossel="LOCAL2" data-desc="LOCAL2" data-modals="street-park-build" id="street-park-build-desc" style="display: none;"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/tab-face/celebrationville/pin.png" class="mapItem itemDefault rotate" id="street-park-build" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Uma dica todas as vezes em que você usar um mesmo seletor da `jQuery` de forma repetida, guarde o resultado da seleção em uma variável pois assim você evita que a `jQuery` fique varrendo o `DOM` em busca do elemento demasiadas vezes.

Comment: Seu código não resolve meu problema, uma vez que citei que trabalho com 12 locais e você setou somente 2. Não há uma forma que funcione para quantos forem necessários?

Comment: Cara se você aumentar a quantidade de locais continua funcionando eu não fiz nada com id fixo exatamente por isso

Comment: O que isso significa: `var toggleClasses = 'modal-celebration portico-build';` Fiquei em dúvida.

Comment: Eu coloquei o seletor em uma variável para evitar de escrever multiplas vezes.

Answer (score 0):

O método [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/), ajudou-me a resolver o problema junto do método [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) que passam os seletores que necessito.

```
$(".mapDesc").not("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "-desc").removeClass("modal-celebration");
```

Comment: lollipop, não era mais simples, armazenar o item ativo na interação anterior, então você remove a class del?.